# Unable to log user events in Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I am trying to use Firebase Analytics and Messaging in my Android App.

The problem is when I do `logEvent` in debug mode `Event not sent since app measurement is disabled` is being showed on my android studio terminal. Also, the event is not reflected on my firebase console.

Below is my code used for `logEvent`

```
FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("button_click", "test");
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("demo", bundle);
```

And also I am able to receive FCM and tokenId from Firebase Messaging.

Comment: Firebase events should not update immediately it's will take 24 hours. If you want test immediately  use debug view https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: Yes @RajasekaranM, I have used debug view which is also not working

Comment: Are you sure you didn't disable events in AndroidManifest.xml?